# Installing the snipMate plugin for MacVim

Tags: vim, snipmate

When I download the snipMate plugin from github and extract to my .vim directory do I have to move the snipMate.vim file to plugins directory that's located in my .vim directory?? The snipmate directory downloaded from github also contains a plugin directory so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directories in the github repository are supposed to mirror the directories within .vim. So, in other words, everything within the 'plugin' directory in the github repo will need to be moved to .vim/plugin. Ditto with 'doc', 'ftplugin', etc.

It might be worth checking out the [Pathogen plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) for vim. It makes installing plugins (particularly ones that are actively maintained and live on sites like github) very simple to manage.

Comment: Thank you very much inkedmn just the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Another question this plugin you just mentioned do I extract it also to my .vim directory

Comment: @CPerez721 Just drop the file in the 'autoload' directory into .vim/autoload and restart vim. You'll need to add a couple of lines to your .vimrc, too - see the README file on the Pathogen page at github.com

Comment: No problem. Please consider up-voting my answer or accepting it as the correct answer :)